# OpenLayers drag control returns wrong XY

Tags: openlayers-2, features, map-drawing, drag-and-drop

I am trying to use a Drag Control in a web GIS. My problem begins when I finish the 'move' of a point. That is, originally the point has an XY like -8.308567019533697 and 41.376871762432685, displaying correctly in the map. After the move, the point has an XY like 49.01610355274739 and -293.0306348131995, displaying very far from the correct place.

My map:

```
var opcoes = {units: 'm', projection:
       epsg_3857,restrictedExtent:extent_maximo,maxExtent:
       extent_maximo,controls: []};

map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',opcoes);
```

The layer of the drag control:

```
var localizador  = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Localizador", {
        isBaseLayer: false,
        styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                'default': est_loc_def,
                "temporary": est_loc_temp
        }),
        displayInLayerSwitcher: false});
```

Comment: You are working in EPSG:3857, which is in meters. Those two points are only a few hundred meters apart. Are you sure this is what you mean?

Comment: Yes. My point is play in the map moving the point inside a city. But when I move a few meters, the point goes to very far from the place where I click.

Comment: You will need to produce a minimal working example for anyone to be able to debug, I think.

Comment: You can see here: http://tests.proasolutions.pt/ Click in the 'streetView' symbol at the top of map and than click in the map. works fine.after that try drag feature and you will see the problem

Comment: Forbidden page :-(

Comment: Sorry, you can try now.

Comment: Which is the streetview symbol? Intervençoes por rua?

Comment: No. The last at the rigth. The tooltip says 'A DEFINIR'.

Comment: I fix it... It was an error on srs of layer...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that code:

'var coords = localizador.features[0].geometry.transform('EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');'

I use that for StreetView and so I was changing the coords moving the point...

Comment: Great. I wondered if it was something like that, but that code wasn't in your question.